# Where can I view my title and meta tags?

Tags: html, title, meta-tags

I feel really stupid, but I can't for the life of me find my title or meta tags in my source code. It just starts out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  .....
</head>
<body>
  ...
```

and then continues like that. I know my title is set, because it's displaying in my tab. This link (https://help.yahoo.com/kb/yahoo-web-hosting/SLN18260.html?impressions=true) tells me the meta tags should be right under the title. So where is the title??? I just want to make sure my meta tags are printing as expected.

---

UPDATE:
Weird, I just found them like halfway down the page, way outside my `<head>`. I don't know what they're doing there, but at least I found them.

Comment: your question is unclear... if you want to see your title, meta tags in the html source, right click your page and click view source, there you can find the title and meta tags at the top of your page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the procedure,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content=".." /> //if needed
<meta name="description" content=".." /> //if needed
</head>
<body>
.....
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<title></title>` should be inside the `<head></head>` block.

Answer (score 1):

Code does not automatically generate tags. Thus, to create a `title` and `meta` tag, just initiate them below the `head` (following convention):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

a proper HTML structure should be like..

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>My title</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      ......
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

[HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html) is the reference to get more ideas about HTML.